# In next js next auth I am getting, Error: Callback for provider type credentials not supported

Tags: next.js, next-auth

My next auth with credentialproviders is working fine on localhost but on my dev server I am getting this error,  " POST https://dev1.mydevserver.us/api/auth/callback/credentials? bad gateway"
There is nothing on server logs, it works on localhost. My NEXTAUTH_URL is "https://dev1.mydevserver.us/" The GoogleProvider and AppleProvider are working fine with callbacks and same url.

My code :

```
        CredentialsProvider({
          name: "Credentials",
          async authorize(credentials, req) {
            try {
              const response = await axios.post(
                "https://dev1.mydevserver.us/auth/api/v1/signin",
                {
                  email: credentials.email,
                  password: credentials.password,
                  apiKey: process.env.GURU_BOT_API_KEY,
                },
                {
                  headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                  },
                }
              );
              if (
                response.data.statusCode === 201 ||
                response.data.statusCode === 200
              ) {
                const user = response.data;
                if (user) {
                  return user;
                }
                return null;
              } else {
                throw new Error("Invalid Credentials");
              }
            } catch (error) {
              throw new Error("Invalid email or password");
            }
          },
        }),
      ],
     cookies: {
    pkceCodeVerifier: {
      name: "next-auth.pkce.code_verifier",
      options: {
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: "none",
        path: "/",
        secure: true,
      },
    },
  },
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, account, user }) {
      if (account) {
        token = Object.assign({}, token, {
          access_token: account.access_token,
          id_token: account.id_token,
          refresh_token: account.refresh_token,
          provider: account.provider,
          user: user,
        });
      }

      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token, user }) {
      if (session) {
        session = Object.assign({}, session, {
          access_token: token.access_token,
          id_token: token.id_token,
          refresh_token: token.refresh_token,
          provider: token.provider,
          user: token.user,
        });

}
      return session;
    },
  },
  session: { strategy: "jwt"},
```

So whats going on here? This is how I am using it in my ui :

```
const status = await signIn("credentials", {
        redirect: false,
        email: email,
        password: password,
        callbackUrl: "/",
      });

      if (status.success) {
        setLoading(false);
        router.push("/");
      }

      if (status.error) {
        setError(status.error);
      }
```

Comment: Solved it, it was not next but my ubuntu server running nginx and its configuration. 

If anyone else facing the same issue, check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38471404/passport-js-express-google-oauth-502-bad-gateway-on-nginx/38758325#38758325