# Session data not persisted across requests - Laravel/Inertia

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, inertiajs

I am trying to save data in session on a post request, which then redirects to another page

```
try {
    $tenant = Tenant::where('email', '=', $request->input('email'))->firstOrFail();
} catch(Throwable $e) {
    return redirect(route('portal.login'))->withErrors(['email' => 'We cannot find any tenant associated with this email address']);
}
    
$this->sendInvite($tenant);

$request->session()->put('tenant', $tenant);
$request->session()->save();

return redirect(route('portal.login.invite'));
```

I have confirmed that the session data has been stored. Below is a DD of the session

```
array:4 [▼ // app/Http/Controllers/PortalController.php:55
  "_token" => "hsD4WKNkqFGsVnOMfPhsDcbpj31UcW10ATyFvOQ2"
  "_flash" => array:2 [▶]
  "_previous" => array:1 [▶]
  "tenant" => App\Models\Tenant {#1381 ▶}
]
```

But when I try and validate for this data on the redirect route, the session data is missing

```
if (!$request->session()->exists('tenant')) {
    dd(session()->all());
    return redirect(route('portal.login'));
}
```

Session data:

```
array:3 [▼ // app/Http/Controllers/PortalController.php:72
  "_token" => "hsD4WKNkqFGsVnOMfPhsDcbpj31UcW10ATyFvOQ2"
  "_flash" => array:2 [▶]
  "_previous" => array:1 [▶]
]
```

Anybody have any ideas why this might be happening? I can share more information upon request

UPDATE:
Changing my session drive to file works, something wrong with the cookie

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this. The problem was that cookie driver has very limited memory when it is stored on browser. Which is why, when I changed the driver from cookie to file it started working because the file driver has larger memory capacity.

So, instead of saving the entire object in the cookie, I saved the ID and it started working

Thanks to this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/46882969/7733157