# Woodmart WooCommerce Social Login URL

Tags: nginx, woocommerce, proxy, fastcgi

I'm running a WooCommerce store and using the Woodmart theme along with Elementor. I'm encountering some issues when trying to enable social login for Facebook and Google.

It works flawlessly in my local environment:
`http://localhost:10010/my-account/?opauth=`

However, it doesn't seem to work in production:
`http://mywebsite.com/my-account?opauth=`

It's missing a "/"

I'm working in incognito.

I've followed [this thread](https://xtemos.com/forums/topic/google-and-facebook-login-error-after-woodmart-update/) from the Woodmart creators

Which led me to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23844761/upstream-sent-too-big-header-while-reading-response-header-from-upstream). I tried to fix the issue by adding a few directives to my Nginx server:

```
fastcgi_buffers         16  16k;
fastcgi_buffer_size     32k;
proxy_buffer_size       128k;
proxy_buffers           4  256k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
```

But still no luck. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may try to regenerate permalinks by going to WordPress Settings > Permalinks and hit "Save changes" button at the bottom.