# Google Cloud Run website timeouts when content length is between 4013-8092 characters. What is going on?

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi, google-cloud-run, fpm

This issue happens on a pure PHP files served by Nginx & PHP-FPM. I've stumbled upon this issue while developing my website using Symfony but the problematic content length range is 3702-15965 for that (I wonder why it's different than vanilla PHP).

What I've tried so far:

- Timeout duration is 15 seconds but I've tried increasing it to 300 seconds and it still timeouts. So I'm guessing it's infinite loopy thing.
- It doesn't look like it's resource related because it works even if content length is 5 million characters.
- Created various tests with different characters to see if I can cause changes to the problematic content length range. Answer is no, range stayed same for all my tests.
- I have tried disabling gzip. It didn't change the length range but the response changed. Gzip enabled response: "upstream request timeout" | Gzip disabled response: Completely blank

Notes:

- This issue doesn't exist on my localhost.
- It **rarely** opens the page normally. I can't reproduce this consistently.
- There are no errors in Nginx, PHP or GCR logs besides the "request timed out" lines.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Funnily enough, I've solved the issue while writing the question. Adding `fastcgi_buffering off;` to Nginx config fixes the issue.

But I still don't understand what was the problem and why disabling buffering fixed it. So if anyone can explain it I don't mind marking that answer as solution.

Comment: Funnily enough, I encountered something similar quite recently. It turned out that I was sending more data than could fit in the fastcgi_buffer_size buffer (my response was 50KB). Bumping the fastcgi_buffer_size (along with fastcgi_buffers and fastcgi_busy_buffers_size) allowed me to keep buffering on and getting everything to work.

Comment: It worked for one file for me, doesn't work on another. Cloud Run is a joke.

Answer (score 4):

This is specific to Nginx and not Cloud Run.

When Nginx starts receiving a response from a FastGCI backend, it will buffer the header response in memory. If the response is too large for memory, a part of it can be saved to a temp file on disk which is controlled by other variables as explained [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_buffering).

By disabling fastcgi_buffering, the response is passed to the client synchronously as it is received. You can find more info in these articles[1][2][3]

[1] [upstream sent too big header while reading response header from upstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23844761/upstream-sent-too-big-header-while-reading-response-header-from-upstream)

[2] [Nginx upstream sent too big header while reading response header from upstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31808400/nginx-upstream-sent-too-big-header-while-reading-response-header-from-upstream)

[3] https://gist.github.com/magnetikonline/11312172#determine-fastcgi-response-sizes

Comment: Thanks for the links but I don't think this explains why timeout happens **only** if content is between 4013-8092 characters (or 3702-15965 when using Symfony).

Comment: PHP internal buffer handling 4096/8092 combined with Nginx internal buffer handling 4096/8092.Consult your Symfony handbook for the PHP buffering options they make use of (or look into the source-code if they hide it from the documentation).

Comment: This can't be specific to nginx, because on other hosting engines it works.