# Cloud run fails to serve complete file - client_disconnected_after_partial_response

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, fastcgi, google-cloud-run, fpm

We have problem in our **PHP application** that runs in GCP **Cloud run**.

Environment: PHP 8 (nginx php-fpm) in docker - official image "php:8.1-fpm".

There are certain files that are failed to be sent to the client when client opens a page in our system. I am **not able to reproduce the same behavior locally** in docker (exactly the same image), so I guess this is Cloud run specific.

The file is served by this PHP code:

```
...
    header('Last-Modified: ' . $lmstring);
    header('Content-Lenght: ' . filesize($filename));
    readfile($filename);
    die;
}
```

Getting this warning from cloud run:

> "Truncated response body. Usually implies that the request timed out or the application exited before the response was finished."

Info log from Google HTTPS load balancer (error code explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/https-logging-monitoring#:%7E:text=client_disconnected_after_partial_response)):

> statusDetails: "client_disconnected_after_partial_response"

Real example and some facts I already found out:
Opening page X in the internal system. This page downloads Y other files - most of these Y files (css+js) are sent successfully, but some are truncated to ~3641 characters. All files that are sent incompletely are usually truncated to the same length (rarely a bit less). It's always the same files trucated and I didn't spot anything they have in common. Sometimes it is js file, sometimes it is css file. The response code is HTTP 200.

I didn't find any error in PHP error output - trying to turn errors on on all levels. We get errors from PHP normally in other cases, so I don't expect anything is silenced.

Anybody has any idea why might this be happening and how to deal with that?

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT: The issue has returned back, so this solution only seems to have made the problem to occur with lower frequency.**

Seems like I found the solution. Answer in following thread has helped:
[Google Cloud Run website timeouts when content length is between 4013-8092 characters. What is going on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63251335/google-cloud-run-website-timeouts-when-content-length-is-between-4013-8092-chara)

Try to explain the behavior is in the above thread too.

Turning the fastcgi bufferring off in nginx helped to get rid of the problem:
`fastcgi_buffering off;` (nginx.conf)