# Ajax posting on localhost but not on VPS host

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, plugins

I've been facing this issue for many days i've searched the whole internet fixed my php.ini even the ngnix.confg file

Please tell me if anything is wrong with the code

i've edited the Cropper Plugin not to download but replace the current image.
so what i did i used the ajax post to do it.
PS: Ajax is sending huge data in post since it's a canvas and this whole process is working fine on localhost but not working on server. The whole site is on laravel but this code is on native php.
I've also figured out that if image is small then it's working fine and if image is large then it's not working on server.

**AJAX code in main.js file**

```
$('.docs-buttons').on('click', '[data-method]', function () {
var $this = $(this);
var data = $this.data();
var $target;
var result;

if ($this.prop('disabled') || $this.hasClass('disabled')) {
  return;
}

if ($image.data('cropper') && data.method) {
  data = $.extend({}, data); // Clone a new one

  if (typeof data.target !== 'undefined') {
    $target = $(data.target);

    if (typeof data.option === 'undefined') {
      try {
        data.option = JSON.parse($target.val());
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.message);
      }
    }
  }

  if (data.method === 'rotate') {
    $image.cropper('clear');
  }

  result = $image.cropper(data.method, data.option, data.secondOption);

  if (data.method === 'rotate') {
    $image.cropper('crop');
  }

  switch (data.method) {
    case 'scaleX':
    case 'scaleY':
      $(this).data('option', -data.option);
      break;

    case 'getCroppedCanvas':
      if (result) {
        var temp =  $(' #image').attr('src');
        jQuery.ajax({
           url: '../../cropper/demo/save.php',
           type: 'POST',
           data: {
               data: result.toDataURL('image/jpeg'),
               name: temp,

           },
           complete: function(data, status)
           {
               console.log(data.responseText);
               if(status=='success')
               {             
                    $('#image').cropper("replace", temp);
               }
               else
                {
                    alert('Error has been occurred');
                }
           }
        });
      }
      break;
  }

  if ($.isPlainObject(result) && $target) {
    try {
      $target.val(JSON.stringify(result));
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e.message);
    }
  }

}
});
```

save.php (To store the image on server)

```
<?php
$based64Image=substr($_POST['data'], strpos($_POST['data'], ',')+1);

$fileName='';
$fileName = substr($_POST['name'], 34);

$image = imagecreatefromstring(base64_decode($based64Image));


if($image != false)
{
    if(!imagejpeg($image,"..\..\images\image\\".$fileName))
    {
    //          fail;
    }
}
else
{
  //          fail;
}

?>
```

Please Help Thanks

Comment: Have you debugged this at all? Checked the console or server log for errors?

Comment: Is your `url` correct?

Comment: this whole thing is working on local host and checked correctly.
but not working on VPS but only works if i put small sized images

Comment: server logs says "upstream sent too big header while reading response header from upstream"

Comment: On server when you are sending, is there any error in `console` or `network`?

Comment: Maybe this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25762111/how-to-fix-upstream-sent-too-big-header-while-reading-response-header-from-upstr

Comment: Why are you cropping the image on the client? Shouldn't you send the coordinates, then crop it on the server?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your conf file

```
fastcgi_buffers 16 16k; 
fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
```

For more details and understanding please read 
https://gist.github.com/magnetikonline/11312172#determine-fastcgi-response-sizes

These results may not be accurate, so reading to ensure your proper configuration is advised

Comment: http://testing2.vire-news.com/public/consumer/create

Please check this is the link

Comment: Checked the link, got an error message about localhost not being allowed to connect to the mySQL server that contained your login and password.