# upstream sent too big header while reading response header from upstream

Tags: nginx, firephp

I'm using nginx and FireBug+FirePHP and I get the error when trying to load a page:

```
upstream sent too big header while reading response header from upstream
```

We are logging a lot of stuff in our dev-enviroment, I guess thats what cause the problem when using FirePHP. After reading similar other questions here on SO, there seems to come to one of the following settings:

```
proxy_buffers 4 256k; (is this same as proxy_buffers 32 32k?)
proxy_buffer_size 128k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
```

or

```
fastcgi_buffers  16 16k;
fastcgi_buffer_size  32k;
```

but it's not really clear where I should add these settings.
I tried to add the proxy-settings to the http-block in my `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`, but I get the message `"proxy_busy_buffers_size" must be less than the size of all "proxy_buffers" minus one buffer` after `nginx -t`. 
next I tried to add the fastcgi-settings to the server-block in my host-file and commented out the proxy-setting lines. `nginx -t` gives no error, but it doesn't seem to work either.

Can someone help me and tell me where exactly to put these lines or if this are the real solutions? Thank you very much. Disabling firePHP would "solve" the problem, but since I need it, this is not really a option.

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25762111/how-to-fix-upstream-sent-too-big-header-while-reading-response-header-from-upstr/25762701#25762701
you place directives properly, but this is FirePHP issue mostly, not nginx

Comment: yeah I know that thread, thats what I tried in my second step. Didn't help though

Answer (score 3):

```
> proxy_buffers 4 256k; 
> proxy_buffer_size 128k;
> proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
```

this solves my problem with nginx reverse proxy to web servers with php + phpconsole