# Server won't allow me to send more than 746 Character in post

Tags: php, linux, apache, post, server

i'am trying to send large blob data made in Canvas after cropping and sending it via ajax to PHP file everything works fine on localhost but on server it doesn't work.
Then i found that my server won't send any data larger than 746 characters.
i've updated the PHP to solve the issue

Changed the line post_max_size to 20M,80M even 0 which means no limit php.ini 
Changed the line upload_max_size to 20M,80M and whatsoever.

The issue still persist.

I'm posting using ajax in jquery.
I've tried the sending 747 character in other forms but it failed but when i enter 746 character it worked.
What might be the issue?
The server is a normal vps host with ubuntu 14 server
Here's the link to the phpinfo of my site
http://adddon.com/info.php

Comment: Did you check the actual error message instead of blindly stabbing in the dark?

Comment: yep it returned
500
Internal Server Error

Sorry, something went wrong :(

Comment: No it didn't. That's not the error message in your log.

Comment: Your Info shows upload_max_filesize and post_max_size as Zero. So I wonder how it even accept 746 characters. Even if it is default installation 2MB  and in some install 8MB in new installation is allowed.

Comment: the php documentation says that setting it to 0 it'll send unlimited data with no limit and a guy wanted to send gigs of data so stackoverflow made this as solution too

Comment: intiially it was 20M but it was still not sending more then that character

Comment: @ShahrukhKhan ... did you restart the httpd service?

Comment: i've restarted the apache on server

Comment: still haven't identified what the specific error is forcing people to guess and ask too many questions

Comment: here's the error log

[error] 1702#1702: *271942 upstream sent too big header while reading response header from upstream

Comment: Your question is tagged 'apache', but that's an nginx error message.

Comment: sorry for the wrong tag but i have tried to fix the issue using this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13894386/upstream-too-big-nginx-codeigniter
waiting for the server to be restarted then i'll tell you the result

Comment: This thread solved my issue
[Proxy Buffer Size Ngnix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13894386/upstream-too-big-nginx-codeigniter)