# Reducing spotify URI to approach max number of allowed tracks

Tags: spotify

The [Spotify Play Button Documentation](http://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-play-button/documentation/) specifies a maximum playlist length of 1000 track. It reads to me like it would just ignore any tracks over 1000:

> Playlist restriction:
>   We only show the first 1000 tracks in any playlist.

**But** I can't even approach that limit before the nginx embed spotify server responds with a

```
Request-URI Too Large
```

For example I have a playlist of 374 tracks but the Spotify server errors when trying to embed a play button. Since stackoverflow won't let me link to embed.spotify.com the full url (data and all) is:

```
http://embed.spotify.com/?uri=spotify:trackset:PartysenseTest:2Foc5Q5nqNiosCNqttzHof,0r2Bul2NuCViraT2zX1l5j,4Li2WHPkuyCdtmokzW2007,5eK3EGtSzTz9eEcPFwE37E,4pWLh2rpIwawP5ExSwvV1V,1oHxIPqJyvAYHy0PVrDU98,6RcQOut9fWL6FSqeIr5M1r,27L8sESb3KR79asDUBu8nW,7Gkphzdh5ouurEt7JT49Yu,5ChkMS8OtdzJeqyybCc9R5,0TDLuuLlV54CkRRUOahJb4,1JP779IkUMANQVaPGzc6Ld,1oF75Qbv8UvOBm1imUAE51,61S6wtjY80a6vHxP3JHSgE,717TY4sfgKQm4kFbYQIzgo,5XwcYDVIxO36IyTa5eelc1,36482hNESSwELpr9sS3NbE,24V2HxXY0yM0lpcpSBYnUU,0nHQAxZgzAcKGRxAsOISTc,4TZZvblv2yzLIBk2JwJ6Un,1kjvBYbo5SgzDVn42c1SuF,5G2c6FsfTzgYUzageCmfXY,6UIwfaQh9RP2anZ5OMQPfX,2W5acFzXf5FrktecuD30Or,5IVuqXILoxVWvWEPm82Jxr,2RUFzxyUlI36KKy9Agkqze,784ExV5zkRPOeIWi8pZhXw,5Z7ygHQo02SUrFmcgpwsKW,2cMTIlktg3M9mXYqCPqw1J,3ZFTkvIE7kyPt6Nu3PEa7V,0OaunKfsxkgBvPv68jBbmm,0nmxH6IsSQVT1YEsCB9UMi,3IYhyHOkfl5YcUoRl5kKUP,5XJJdNPkwmbUwE79gv0NxK,1fn6EFBBNiDVhL3DxDDJTD,1cHa7GjYbLCK9z3lWN1rVC,1CRFWfZEfLCs7pYDlXFYMJ,5jRDHEemZKcEWSfZDjmAjq,3FteycP8CaXS1MhjcXekVT,2ENx9vLmbagrc0yDY1j0BN,7oQSevUCbYs4QawXTHQVV1,3bidbhpOYeV4knp8AIu8Xn,3r2EtAEybamz9jJm8W47lA,0aj2QKJvz6CePykmlTApiD,4Tyv7nnNTHC6mR1pTubIrw,4ZOyH6KjomjlqCz3oFqglr,07dYGGSrzPeg6a3KZjWX65,2rgqPSIRAfaO2MGo9smdSX,0OJtYfqiz0Xn53o2TnySQC,4DoiEk7AaubTkIkYencvx7,5T9Kx7b2NrZdHiEshXdDrK,5YPMEOJ58kfl56VHxTgwx3,1V4jC0vJ5525lEF1bFgPX2,666elemQTQGi8xbjAAdIgB,5qPmR4nG3nNAECAN5JxrEV,0vEN1H3ySpduTY5Etmlznn,0CAfXk7DXMnon4gLudAp7J,7oK9VyNzrYvRFo7nQEYkWN,0fuP0ykgrDSxk5odNU7Gy2,0XzkemXSiXJa7VgDFPfU4S,1Je1IMUlBXcx1Fz0WE7oPT,7HqIvbMMdI6QvAnCACvn6F,3MjUtNVVq3C8Fn0MP3zhXa,6c4w7qJd1gTmr90spDfUyM,0Yo8GhK9HEaeIZetPARrW9,1WGvP3bZ5rp9CiQZNiNjXc,0SLtqCrXBRrnkxSOMA3X4W,56fwHfJaBpaauvFJrnwk2L,7BHPGtpuuWWsvE7cCaMuEU,0Ny4yM9JFFuCUZ497ouxKe,2ijsITOdUkUeF8EW7OfYBr,0k5fY8c9fwMdnE1nSlp0Rw,5y8WWi1BaKHXfuln0XoIZs,2XDdHuoRmBeOaBIOSclj2k,46iI0binWzpkEJgIWTYUBR,2bNrvWD9d5Zn9tS8XvcaMk,6wwAaPoX7Ce81Rn85Ntm89,0R7YVi7w41Dr9jU5vblAok,0CRJioCflddFvP2SLKZRyS,3Zuf70897YkrVRAsrBMMSF,541dIJFHxpeCMVWydZ5Lzw,2Cd9iWfcOpGDHLz6tVA3G4,0RJWhctsc1G1Hg3Ov2th7x,0dQQWHlXvuw4UyHcAvhfhB,5TXNLJ2EENAt3Tf9MX4kT2,23aiLB7EO71B4WrFYYzlAL,6EuArluBSbxlFs4vtQ3cYR,4WbNyQy4wVdfopMrApBWQA,5iaMh3rhscSYEdLGDmA2Cd,0MTW23wOFcSscAOcTqShye,6cskzfZWgrgd8hv74fHd9o,4hy4fb5D1KL50b3sng9cjw,28p3b7gryOjhe5HAcNFWhJ,6t6oULCRS6hnI7rm0h5gwl,2GAIycsMaDVtMtdvxzR2xI,0f0lWRAs9kdAFZu8mAI9K2,0Ph6L4l8dYUuXFmb71Ajnd,4DEmKidTANibjgv2XLVk2L,05SBRd4fXgn8FX7bf8BCAE,7hMqIrwysNlIXRmFCIn5j3,57PjISfyOyDcvTPipz16nf,0teP3TUc015sRFqUaeyfh8,0gZp88SA5OcujHLDGkxtI3,7FZh3I56BkVHpodjxAJcIL,47uhrF6IvyE2eUyyfLAEzf,5zdUc1JRCImBYcDWgvFNpE,5R9a4t5t5O0IsznsrKPVro,6kopmMZiyLmw7h66uXcXR7,0S7zL7ae0KpOSPKeFQpHo8,70cTMpcgWMcR18t9MRJFjB,4KCjaHCQMIyi0x1sTTQV2j,1D066zixBwqFYqBhKgdPzp,32yIEFS62uS5ryhr2Xlooj,7kMfu3KUydmrFVGEAhjtyl,3VZQshi4COChhXaz7cLP02,7B1Dl3tXqySkB8OPEwVvSu,1YUYuJKfRQOd5c4qp4xqpL,4efOmCxdddbbzKGlb9iAok,2DHc2e5bBn4UzY0ENVFrUl,0ltBH1JNzSvQJPjJpvTu9B,7xV6oF0LMnrXKEs6JrWQXf,0xcl9XT60Siji6CSG4y6nb,0FRelX0g1nNDFt6nvtiakE,6BCNGfQacMqawqzK5Iaqrr,1sn6iOK93jnp0Hn5BnNOXy,03AIRTc1MIGDa4Lpnp0pqP,7w87IxuO7BDcJ3YUqCyMTT,4HRa9ZWcmZ8JD7UySPu0wT,53jqLK3wUEy0gCucIOkno7,24efdUt3KGbZ6wnBLp6j2n,1wSFyAwUGqrLauh3MdjMsM,3BxWKCI06eQ5Od8TY2JBeA,1gZ7i4qxXkHZb1r6eioaAP,1lkC6oC7SbwgnEBEC05r64,6mnjcTmK8TewHfyOp3fC9C,5jaz6aiRknA63NIYWdbr2O,4srpHYFHKjVGRDNHqRpWxi,4P7VFiaZb3xrXoqGwZXC3J,36TBMtrW4x7bHW8LH8rnRr,4SphTMCxlllfYZMyny8BPO,1hKdDCpiI9mqz1jVHRKG0E,5619Ojc6t9evEEs3B7Drhe,6eFahAdQgABBj1XOM99cBG,2nMeu6UenVvwUktBCpLMK9,3GCL1PydwsLodcpv0Ll1ch,0nypsuS2jtogLaJDcRQ4Ya,3uuGbRzMsDI5RiKWKOjqWL,519uJbE3zyKLlToVA65PrP,5ssDVF6DwLv0z93CoxHgPZ,1EFbV1t25dXy9FhKN1OIqq,5pzSsipRTmu2tD9I3Nihxw,5ve0BYRZZ2aoHFqZMxqYgt,3X7abqSXC4xrxuC1ykpWcY,6jaHYV4no6PAbyo89bybrx,1MiXdrxHJGH2NzS11wqmvV,1GBknQ67DCfKTPms1dw9EW,2t0ZYmVXMR36fchq1Egs2d,6QPKYGnAW9QozVz2dSWqRg,1Q3KZbKwcY6d6IaOZwDzil,5unfeZUhKhICP73CDYBW4N,0laYHRpNTS6i8FXdupHkJ4,36RBVJLpBiiBakoMw9FmOV,5WTxbyWTpoqhdxEN2szOnl,3c6m2f4AV6IXbkiSOlSjuo,4cluDES4hQEUhmXj6TXkSo,1OmxpKVSvn0LGcM3SQS4OV,22sLuJYcvZOSoLLRYev1s5,14iN3o8ptQ8cFVZTEmyQRV,0IZM2onaTBMRTEIcc5oIi9,7Hv89f7Dpm5Hce1XkBbjQZ,4vVTI94F9uJ8lHNDWKv0i2,6RGvWCHTS6BC46TsMyN0WM,3VJSaH6uE1FXzlUOlpO9Mu,6nn59FOFejiDZbqcu1clyy,4bxI9ChxEjVVqtFZmWRrR4,5l6tv2lFylSdCgkWyfHC0P,305WCRhhS10XUcH6AEwZk6,0rXgKeO7DWMiXCmNDhkRdd,12qZHAeOyTf93YAWvGDTat,7eusnHDVdvqjUGAigj77XC,5FeuH4LtGxDWkSkhRG47QT,6l1naSGJiwFdVlg9H8g6w9,1xN7BpTAWnZkuSLOtRP6Qc,4c5ZzFEXngHlf1KRoaLH0Z,7s0lDK7y3XLmI7tcsRAbW0,4pGv2AFdSV6N2VwAaVciW0,3GC3xIxWImpR7dfv2F81ze,6nDC9ivU0g3mX29OFgynCc,76Je5Wklky23mVoxiRszcN,4xanWVQIzdCf51mg8cd1cQ,0ancVQ9wEcHVd0RrGICTE4,0q5xRODc3CcDS48dPaHjA7,6BLLQndvA0rLbLcIZmuuEJ,65mxB9IWpmVo4qUjdGSxRB,0gsLWzySRe81KoY4LENNY4,3khUMqi9iGgOpgReFwjbZl,4WcCW10tnJCljX8Fhs0FdE,3aImJnJlAgcE7bJ1NxthGt,6vYznTXaytbE7r3aSfLZyb,1XduQVon3QYUTHrQJNKN7z,4k80K0b6KZ2QjAYkXON7q6,7bprRkhvOXWmWpqOrEWbXu,12lZTPlXwUtrQuhEty6098,5FQazQxWUHsJ8QDaXLdFzR,6aJmDsQaB3KDTJWVc4cCbI,3jNyatJv1JxuIlwKoYlo7Y,5JzF2iymNwCyFz9MTmojd0,15HadeuRG9THazDGzLH8ZU,1C2CPvmL5R6nODesaZF4df,20BpvfS6lIbi083TyPePMn,175MNUY1aNnGCFfCyNZz2m,45MR4PKygkmQvHovjBBOla,1lDWb6b6ieDQ2xT7ewTC3G,1DDsYldutVWnRrRbZc5X5B,5vlEg2fT4cFWAqU5QptIpQ,1B75hgRqe7A4fwee3g3Wmu,1HRThJebs60Dk6jAhpkwsm,7y8cq2fiwZK0Ed0dbnP6gV,0AfYeE3bfJRcq9J2hUJXmM,21K6jcmZPktm7MftqfLfLg,4GzDUKkd1RwAtYZMMUBM3W,32Z4ioCoKKsKMFS9vhzkJJ,1JR0kZfJpeNPJKo4HhdQJP,5yEPktRqvIhko5QFF3aBhQ,0HnaqUxvHP5LaWdmWwJpiS,7EOq26yQNd2edGERHSNZbX,6YgV0EF8xJMZz0Zm6BTaT4,63EadEcC2ZwLencVf12SmI,2NwuwbqiCJqnxC4yKh0Fqp,2tP7ZekzXfduShx8C6cbll,6BFy7jDjmBIero9RvFyiFR,1CNJyTUh56oj3OCZOZ5way,0gfrYOlmcuC4RHQDWkJNVC,77NNZQSqzLNqh2A9JhLRkg,6oWpGuwokWJ4EcWgVQPdUt,0YAJcefABZHD0D3KcYpSdR,2OeSwSbwlmn9u8SsutfxPO,2YHdhu31gouUkRONb5BfQX,294vBlXfZYspeI29SXZaON,3oYyowEl145Var54G6Uwia,12Ns5IphkblPmHxpRILG9t,0K7P82sgDDgdeUisBVRQ6t,7kz6GbFr2MCI7PgXJOdq8c,2KELpXHhIQh1vzeC0vtV6V,6jC0lQjWvu5fPepbWM5C64,2id8E4WvczfKHB4LHI7Np3,6uJzljaQjB3oAgirQTdter,79KIMUAkOLIREcEy859KSh,7C86DVl6REN8VPeGEMOf9q,4bz7uB4edifWKJXSDxwHcs,5LRxSyiIRHQD26h1mdM0Ir,2yWyFT6bW1Rd9cjVvYi4v8,7fqRbZ0MFnaYZaGGy8eFAB,0nVIEAzQNWZzCl3MSZttD5,7g8cjrj0sXScNE727685JE,5L3WZ6b9F1wwVOlcxr9uEL,2rjOaGr1mcTYePllS8crRf,7pEKFqDrq6yKOADSmchOdT,52gvlDnre9craz9dKGObp8,1tjY4H0X706ZH03SXa1DFh,7gpy7sfWPNuOKmUNs3XQYE,66S14BkJDxgkYxLl5DCqOz,5PKWUDfQFtc5qqo8cs1gQp,4fa6GtKatbIDX7WrdA9xNP,3ehrxAhYms24KLPG8FZe0W,7frWizM5FgJkaUl1rXhVtO,7ukQvPuGUBZt88WveKBGAD,7MTvJ1opaAkaEx0guBsjWR,0AkQbXGN4KG34TS7xLrM68,1z3ugFmUKoCzGsI6jdY4Ci,4lCv7b86sLynZbXhfScfm2,455AfCsOhhLPRc68sE01D8,209NkbzmsUa9pAobU7xGyf,0wFd8ei34BCH8R5pkMVNyb,1dzQoRqT5ucxXVaAhTcT0J,6umBxaxgV2q52o3Q8wH2Ma,1hVQx6bg4uKPljAUkNjpY2,5mKlJovDkSuMXOMTX5Vuzn,4CLZ3D2RCI5ZCfB51D6NwB,5Q7cE6wGHMehLFo2ppkk5D,1HOMkjp0nHMaTnfAkslCQj,5HbCnVLXRyZVxnreOPgJCK,2P3YqXTNK1EIpI0iMv7acb,1mXXf7ztqQei9qUXliL19H,4VySpxhRGy32u5zPCprzDn,6KRi6CBUitENJB4HQbSVSD,5Utz5NBlQnUTpiy56fUHfh,0GrrLYCH8u81aENhC8FBF4,7fG22bvpAT44rkKgYDLmFK,38XRTf7XdStVxVXdCqQq3F,1y3gjjO01zJDM2oTGljMb4,0XMaNd9OogazR9negEAKGP,1dZ6svgHGRCvtFLyUEWsEY,1DC0dOPid7keTB8QvYiKSb,7wnWXT3AofUyUfR1i33Axn,6CqR4kUwJySVaQPLP49E1V,09a1y2b11vF75PEX6nEdwz,0pdfQUMcAYFv0vlRdFnQ0F,5Xgf7vtIZQGaVvhrE18WV0,1AeKqTY9v9ZnnvoIrbSa5E,4FeKqAKb2YwUQoS26767lI,0YYbQESOOReEZjVzbYJtMC,3jEpAd0vOH6rHqzKnoSVj9,7gF9RfiO8nBhFhBkLuiUrb,0cqNGWvuukhCiKvEX7utys,3rpReNtrRZudNhHrYEjOyZ,6vpQluFwjbt4ZEl8mw6swS,72jGj8k9C7DIQesDYenUT3,4f2aGfZngFF8lQ5pgw9xPV,5KqldkCunQ2rWxruMEtGh0,18CvTk4qxJ5A8PLXxhUFH3,0HLTDZfWuf7pwDtgHvFqce,5s9Lyn5L3apAg4t8wtznqh,7bpvfjoneSQvW0tbtVm1Jk,3XnlnG1NTylhLUCCJQiFOv,0rqCCH30sxXPlMYoo2mk2A,4urcG6Nfubqsuqy3juMjBi,6hzUhWGMBWKntf3kcv0oGu,0Xw7YLRhKWJoZkYMusD4uy,3fRlFGB8bVvpRuUt3iJlwS,1jypmXUJgxWKWJZdDsJiXQ,3TcL0dyCMyr0kyTTc4NLgI,23WsKRReucDjMli5fuRwkn,3Q3UzZpqgoojXj6OncnBVG,563HSFCHokFZGaNL4WY4dY,2dzMbi6uW2EE4cgzxf8vcO,6hs3SDnbO3f6VQuPO4KBEb,4P73qgh9VA1S9Hct6VhLI4,1A0sm1VORvPPaerkrYbNpp,6HHfwQ5xBAtTN6T9FwGfxA,46OM6fMgHBwYMQXY8DmBQ0,3Otjx9ULpmWdUbkDTYDXHc,2JQRlt3HpTCpRvcfDsbwic,5Y55FgnTswJip7H7HfCOpa,7CxhdANGZEPZ3BoTjFMKP3,5kBUuO23N07Gfpe2Gp2f0I,1xLPuXP6RINjOmVg5OOJ3S,3pRURfm0THUY3G4YBOLtrC,5E0DnZaFssI89buDotaYUs,1H5tvpoApNDxvxDexoaAUo,6xKtyif1fN1kJ5zT9KqS87,1iaIEmZHrjGzWUmJ9BaFr6,2pjZHqU5AnDfwNMa3qpCpA,4ue5ET9msGNJSO6sSbrCVE,1jgmL1VK9U7XyKIOfVBbqJ,43OdYMY7yMgBW3n5W4QQD9,4nCKVeS3P17GflmYSno6N2,7yUolETfcL5eB96wCp5Jfh,3G4ILqK22FWxui4BJWJRTN,2Ps4FrDiR6JcJfSZbXAPBz,3fT9nfnv5uLyPsx6ymre7z,0a4agFmqHXxcZl1nho1BxM,0vLwL4xuJ3s7SeaCdvMqkY,6UklT59S3G6z31JfeR05EA,4HuHoYjNcbGIHFpRVbRj2T,2T4u39au5RJzsulMUpRuVr,60wwxj6Dd9NJlirf84wr2c,0r9Dtmw0gstt9eC2dAjf2Z,18eoNBn1L1li2TvPa2DupB,09nxdcY2oYo57fJrG6CCCT,2oTDOIAdsxPTE7yAp4YOcv,1R2SZUOGJqqBiLuvwKOT2Y,1mKXFLRA179hdOWQBwUk9e,1nInOsHbtotAmEOQhtvnzP,6li2D8wQPvgwI2QIrGPhAF,19vqpjwWDbPmizICIUFinw,5iqtsXxZGiN31wlVcbMyaZ,3bINd6fURyFLT0sQwkjbCG,3iY7VgZ1T95LlFro7ccEBV,4pjicGblm2xHknzyjnDOPy,5dhqm5q3v82iAksbks2MTU,6CnuehRR8GVXJfzCs25GX9,2HZduZZqZzfhYEUjibkxq1,5U8dy2VxCGMXCy5b9ZfzO4,&view=list
```

Are there any known ways around this? Is it possible to POST the information to the Spotify server to create a (public) playlist for instance?

Can we manage a playlist at all via any web APIs? Would creating a server based program that used libspotify to create playlists be an option?

Comment: Just tested it with an open.spotify url and got the same thing

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is talking about playlists, not track sets. A playlist URI looks like this:

`spotify:user:ikenndac:playlist:0itp4msnza3If8mxZoTYcy`

If you paste that URI into the play button it'll list the tracks within. If the playlist has more than 1,000 tracks in it, only the first 1,000 will be shown.

Track sets are indeed limited by the standard URI size limits.

Comment: The documentation talks about both - the section mentioning the restriction of 1000 tracks is followed by the documentation of "Multiple tracks player". There is no mention of a separate limit.

Comment: I think this isn't even hitting the api, rather nginx can't process the url size. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067334/how-to-set-the-allowed-url-length-for-a-nginx-request-error-code-414-uri-too