# Nginx returns empty response on long URL - (failed) net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: google-chrome, nginx

I'm running several nginx servers that are only writing the requests being made to a log file.
lately I've noticed that long URLs are not being processed by the nginx. nginx doesn't even log the calls as errors or info or any other level of debug and I'm getting the
(failed) net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

error message instead.

If I reduce the number of chars for this url, it works fine. I'm trying to figure out if I can create a different setup instead of splitting the file to several small calls.

Comment: Haven't you found a solution? I'm facing the same problem. First, it returned 414, but then I set `client_header_buffer_size` and `large_client_header_buffers` settings (see [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067334/how-to-set-the-allowed-url-length-for-a-nginx-request-error-code-414-uri-too) and [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23732147/configuring-nginx-for-large-uris?lq=1), and it started to return 404.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your nginx config file:

```
client_header_buffer_size 64k;
large_client_header_buffers 4 64k;
```