# Nginx response 414 URI Too Long even with very large large_client_header_buffers setting

Tags: nginx

I am using `nginx version: nginx/1.10.1` and proxy to Rails app. I need to accept a very long URL and I update it with

```
client_header_buffer_size 512k;
large_client_header_buffers 4 512k;
```

But this only works for URL length around 8'000 characters. URL with more than that will not work.

I tried to put these header settings into `http {}` and `server {}` block, but does not work.

Did I miss anything? It should work according to Nginx's doc http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_header_buffer_size

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1067462/2428119

Comment: This link suggests that it's your backend (as in Rails, behind Unicorn or Passenger or whatever you're using) that's having the problem at this pont: https://www.ruby-forum.com/t/nginx-returning-414-even-when-large-client-header-buffers-is-set/218717/6