# Nginx url limit 502 gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

I have a question but I accept other suggestions that bypass this feature.

Basically I'm sending big lines of text ~3000 characters to my server in a get request and the server sends it to google translate as params in a url.

The problem: Nginx throws me a 502 bad gateway error when the url is > 1900 characters.

How can I increase the limit of my nginx url?

Alternative Solution: Sending a post request with the 3000 characters in a JSON as a string?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're sending it as a GET url parameter? What surprises me is that you're getting a 502 (Bad Gateway) instead of a 414 (Request-URI Too Large)

Comment: That's how google expects it so I guess I had the pattern in my head. I guess I had it in my head and it worked on my local machine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To answer your question, there is a setting you can change in the nginx.conf file containing your server's configuration.

Set the following setting to something that seems fitting to your situation:

```
large_client_header_buffers 4 16k;
```

Find the documentation for it [here.](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#large_client_header_buffers)

I would suggest to use a POST request in case your ~3000 character requests get bigger and your nginx configuration reaches it limit.

Comment: Thanks man. I actually solved it by going with POST request. It's true I was holding my head against the wall with those huge get requests

Comment: I too get a 502 err. Seems docs are inconsistent: ```large_client_header_buffers Sets the maximum number and size of buffers used for reading large client request header. A request line cannot exceed the size of one buffer, or the 414 (Request-URI Too Large) error is returned to the client. ```

Answer (score 7):

The important thing to notice here is that a 502 error is a problem downstream. You're probably using nginx as a reverse proxy, and it's the service that you're forwarding to which is failing.

In my case, I was using nginx to forward traffic to a docker instance which was using uwsgi. So I needed to up the 'buffer-size' parameter in my uwsgi configuration. But your specific solution will depend on the service that you're forwarding to.