# NGINX rewrite rule with agruments

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I have the case that need to rewrite the URL

The old URL:

```
https://abc.local/ui/navigation/data/vsphere.core.folder.monitor.eventsView?objectId=urn:vmomi:Folder:group-d1:bffc54a1-3add-487a-8c5a-4d03f759d1fe
```

The new URL:

```
https://abc.local/ui/
```

Could you please help me. How can I do it?

Many thanks

Comment: Try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49191594/nginx-rewrite-a-lot-2000-of-urls-with-parameters/49192527#49192527).

Comment: Does the new url have to be https://abc.local/ui/ or https://abc.local/ui/?objectId=urn:vmomi:Folder:group-d1:bffc54a1-3add-487a-8c5a-4d03f759d1fe 

?

Comment: @flaixman the new url only is abc.com/ui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
map $request_uri $redirect {
    default 0;
    /ui/navigation/data/vsphere.core.folder.monitor.eventsView?objectId=urn:vmomi:Folder:group-d1:bffc54a1-3add-487a-8c5a-4d03f759d1fe  https://abc.local/ui/;

}


server {
    if ($redirect) {
    return 301 $redirect;
}
```

As Richard say, this should work. Map the request uri outside of the server bracket, and then inside it set the if with a redirect to your wanted url.

Comment: It seem that the long URI here is not accepted by Nginx, it can not start the nginx service if i use this URL in the map the request uri. Do you have any solutions for this? Thanks a lot
/ui/navigation/data/vsphere.core.folder.monitor.eventsView?objectId=urn:vmomi:Folder:group-d1:bffc54a1-3add-487a-8c5a-4d03f759d1fe  https://abc.local/ui/;

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067334/how-to-set-the-allowed-url-length-for-a-nginx-request-error-code-414-uri-too

Does this help?