# Laravel homestead - site cant be reached when query string length exceeds 5564 chars?

Tags: nginx, vagrant, query-string, homestead, laravel-7

I'm running Laravel 7 on homestead on a windows 10 machine. I've noticed when a url query string exceeds 5564 chars I get the following error in chrome and similar error in firefox and edge.

```
This site can't be reached
dev.mytestsite.com unexpectedly closed the connection.
```

Any ideas why this is happening, is there a limit to query string length or some server setting I can configure?

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067334/how-to-set-the-allowed-url-length-for-a-nginx-request-error-code-414-uri-too  and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686217/maximum-on-http-header-values. Probably that will help  you to figure out.

Comment: @mgsxman hi, yes I've had a look a those but I'm not seeing any error codes inthe browser?

Comment: Any errors at Nginx or Server logs?