# How to configure Nginx .conf files on Azure App Services

Tags: python, nginx, azure-web-app-service

I am getting an error with an Azure App Services (Python) with Nginx for a Bad Gateway. [Investigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067334/how-to-set-the-allowed-url-length-for-a-nginx-request-error-code-414-uri-too) led to me understand that the URL length was too long for Nginx to handle. So I need to adjust the [large client head buffers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067334/how-to-set-the-allowed-url-length-for-a-nginx-request-error-code-414-uri-too)

But when I try to access the nginx .conf files it seems I am not [allowed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/waws/things-you-should-know-web-apps-and-linux#CIFS) to do it.

Is there a way to achieve this?

```
client_header_buffer_size 5120k;
large_client_header_buffers 16 5120k;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have try to set redirect setings like you in default.conf file. I can set it successfully, but few minutes later, it's gone. I can't find nginx folder and default.conf file.

All my try is failed,So I think we don't have permissions to change that like your link said.

So I recommand you create custom container with nginx to host your webapp. It will help you solve the issues.

**Offical doc:**

[1. Migrate custom software to Azure App Service using a custom container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-custom-container?pivots=container-linux)

[2. uwsgi-nginx-docker](https://github.com/tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-docker)