# 414 Error Request - URI too Large Through Postman

Tags: java, api, rest, get

I have a GET request with huge number of parameters and it works fine whenever I hit it through the browser but whenever I try to hit the same request through Postman, I get - "414 error - Request URI Too Large | nginx".
This is something weird cause I am getting the results through browser.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

From postman you have the possibility to copy the request as curl, from the right sidebar. There is a </> sign. Click on it and click on copy snippet.

Then open the inspect console in the browser, go to network tab, find your request and right-click -> copy -> copy as curl.

Then you should check the differences between them. Postman add some headers when a requests is executed so this may be the cause.

If you can update nginx configuration

From: http://nginx.org/r/large_client_header_buffers

```
Syntax: large_client_header_buffers number size ;
Default: large_client_header_buffers 4 8k;
Context: http, server
```

More details about how to update nginx configuration regarding this issue you can find in this post
[How to set the allowed url length for a nginx request (error code: 414, uri too large)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067334/how-to-set-the-allowed-url-length-for-a-nginx-request-error-code-414-uri-too)